# Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled

Tags: android, gson

i am getting this error on logcat:

What is the reason behind this error:

```
getGoogleAppId` failed with status: 10,
            Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

Comment: Can you add the log error trace to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use `GSON` why did you mix it with `JSONObject`?

```
Post[] beanPostList = new Gson().fromJson(response, Post[].class);
```